# Запросы в Access

Tags: access

Мне нужно задать запрос на выборку, чтобы вывести список пассажиров, купивших билеты в первом квартале текущего года.

Я задаю `Year([Дата] )= Year(Now()) And DatePart("q", [Дата] ) = 1`, но в итоге у меня выводится ошибка, что пропущен операнд, введен недопустимый знак или лишняя запятая либо задана строка без ковычек. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

в запросах акцесса разделителем операндов служит точка с запятой.